# how can i pass byte array to asyncTask?

Tags: java, android-asynctask, android-studio, byte

Android Studio throws this error when I use byte[]

ERROR:
expected parameters: byte[]
actual parameters:   byte[][]

and this error when I pass byte: "type argument cant be of primitive type"

```
class PrintOrderTaskSTARIO extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

     ......

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... print) {

    String portName = "";
    String portSettings = "9100";

    StarIOPort port = null;
    System.out.println("2");

    //TRY TO PRINT....
    try
    {
        port = StarIOPort.getPort("tcp:10.1.10.18", "9100", 10000);

        //Start checking the completion of printing
        port.writePort(print, 0, print.length);
```

Comment: What does `byte...` mean? What does `byte[]...` mean?

Comment: Because you're using `byte[]` as varargs.

Comment: I cant pass byte because "type argument cant be of primitive type"